# How do I make a maven dependency available to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, maven

I'm trying to "include" various Jars/libraries with Tomcat 7.0 (typically I'd put them in the tomcat/lib directory) to make Tomcat JSR 109 compliant.

So, I added some dependencies and made them "system", hoping that a system-wide dependency would be available to Tomcat on startup. Unfortunately, even though browsing through the packages in my dependency list, shows all the classes Tomcat is looking for, Tomcat doesn't seem to have access to them or know where they are.

Please advise...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.0EA3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${path.jaxwsrt}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Added Note: I'd like Tomcat itself, not just the application it's running to access it. Examples are:

- Spring Tomcat Instrumentable Classloader
- Catalina Extensions for Apache Commons Logging and Web Services Support

Comment: What pom does the example `<dependency>` come from? Not sure I understand the question. If you've added the jars to Tomcat's server libs, then a Maven built WAR can use these jars by using `provided` as the dependency scope. No `<systemPath>` required.

Comment: I think he wants Tomcat to get the jars from Maven, essentially.

Comment: Yeah, I want Tomcat (on startup) to be able to have access to my maven dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

That's not what system scope means.  System scope says to Maven: "This dependency is part of my system. You don't need to bundle it when I deliver an artifact because it's already in the system.  You don't need to download it when compiling or running tests, because I'm giving you the path to it just here."  (You have to give the path, for system-scope dependencies.)

The standard way to make JARs available to Tomcat is to put them in the WAR.  This will happen if you set the scope to "compile" or "runtime".

Another approach would be to put the JARs into the shared directory of Tomcat, and set their scope to "provided".  If you do this, you're running off a non-standard Tomcat distribution and you need a process to manage this (otherwise you're going to have trouble one day with people not understanding why your app won't run on a vanilla Tomcat install).

Short reminder on Maven scopes:

compile = "I need this when I compile, when I compile tests, when I run tests, and when I execute the project, and you need to bundle it in the deliverable because it isn't already in the runtime environment".

runtime = "My code will compile without this, but it's going to look for it at runtime, including when running tests, and it isn't provided in the runtime environment, so could you please bundle it in the deliverable."

provided = "My code needs this to compile, and when running tests and in production, so I need it on the classpath for compilation and tests, but you don't need to bundle it because the runtime environment provides it."

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat isn't aware of maven or its dependencies.
If you want to change tomcat behavior (and not only your application - i.e. WEB-INF/lib), you would need to either:

- launch tomcat from maven after injecting your extra dependencies
- have an additional build step which deploys the extra libraries to a 'well known' tomcat install
- repackage your private version of tomcat with extra libs, then use it to host your app

In all cases, this belongs to a separate maven module as it has nothing to do with your application. If you want to do any of this, the tomcat maven plugin source might be a good starting point.

Comment: option 2 "have an additional build step which deploys the extra libraries to a 'well known' tomcat install" seems like the simplest option in this case... Any further thoughts?

Comment: It definitely is the simplest way to do it - the problem is that your build is now relying on some local setup/properties which makes life slightly harder if you need to build on a large number of machines.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using system scope, cause if i check [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjaxws-rt) it can be found.

Comment: I'm wanting to share the jars with the "system". Maybe I'm using it incorrectly, but I'm trying to make the jars "available" to Tomcat.

Comment: If you like to have them in Tomcat add the dependencies to your project and recreate the war which will contain the dependencies...

Comment: What do you mean by put them in the war? Stick the actual JAR in WEB-INF/libs?

Comment: Yes. Do you mean something different ?